# How do I make rotations so that colliders from other objects are taken into account in unity?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Situation. There is a player, he is empty, which has a collider capsule, rb + scripts for movement, and so on.
There is a camera, she is the daughter of this player, she has a script that rotates the camera.
And finally, there is a hand (I tried to make a daughter for both the player and the camera), which should not pass through other colliders, but it does it all the time, conditionally I have a cube, and I wave my hand and it goes through the cube.
How to make sure that the hand does not pass through them? I tried to hang the Rb + collider on my arm and rotate it through Rb, but I couldn't achieve an adequate result. I saw an example through an additional camera and a layer, but I'm not sure that this is the only option and I would like to find out others.
I tried rotating the camera through AddTorque and MoveRotation, but no result

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

 public class CameraController : MonoBehaviour
{

public Transform playerTransform;
public float sensitivity = 2.0f;
public float rotationSpeed = 2.0f;

private float verticalRotation = 0;
private Rigidbody rb;

void Start()
{
    Cursor.lockState = CursorLockMode.Locked;
    Cursor.visible = false;

    rb = playerTransform.gameObject.GetComponent<Rigidbody>();

    rb.freezeRotation = true;
}

void FixedUpdate()
{
    float mouseX = Input.GetAxis("Mouse X") * sensitivity;

    float mouseY = -Input.GetAxis("Mouse Y") * sensitivity;
    verticalRotation += mouseY;
    verticalRotation = Mathf.Clamp(verticalRotation, -90f, 90f);

    rb.MoveRotation(Quaternion.Euler(verticalRotation, playerTransform.eulerAngles.y, 
  0));
     }
  }
```